# Retrieving JSON values from var within a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

The below function is throwing me a TypeError and I'm trying to understand why.  Bascially I have a JSON (var test) that is a JSON and I'm trying to access another var's (blogspotter) JSON data.  For my script blogspotter needs to be a dynamic JSON.  If I take the JSON found in blogspotter and copy it into static value (caseJSON) it works, but if I try to do it via a var (caseVAR) I get an error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
function stackerFlow (d) {    
var blogspotter = getAllowedIntervals ()   
   ///  getAllowedIntervals returns the exact JSON as found in test.caseJSON   

var test = {
  "caseJSON" : {"interval":{"start_month":12,"start_year":2014,"end_month":12,"end_year":2017}}
  "caseVAR" : blogspotter     
}

Logger.log (blogspotter)    /// returns a valid JSON
Logger.log(test.caseJSON.interval.start_month)  /// returns 12
Logger.log(test.caseVAR.interval.start_month)   //// throws an error - "TypeError: Cannot read property "start_month" from undefined.
}
```

Comment: did you try JSON.parse()

Comment: what does `getAllowedIntervals ()` do ? Is it synchronous ?

Comment: You might want to post the result of `Logger.log (blogspotter)  `

Comment: Also do `Logger.log(typeof(blogspotter))`. If it says `string` then you'll need to do `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Please, please, please do not confuse JSON and JavaScript object. Your variable test is not JSON. JSON is a specific format used to pass data between systems.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone - I checked the typeof and it was indeed a string so using JSON.parse did the trick and now it is working.
Re: JSON vs JS Object, you are right and thanks for pointing that out.  Still learning...

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your code a bit so I could run it easily. I added the getAllowedIntervals function so it returns the blogspotter as you said and added a comma before "caseVar".
If you save my code in something like test.htm, open it in mozilla, open the console(click anywhere and choose "inspect element") and click on the stackerflow button you can see it runs fine:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function getAllowedIntervals() {
        return {"interval":{"start_month":12,"start_year":2014,"end_month":12,"end_year":2017}};
    }
    function stackerFlow () {    
        var blogspotter = getAllowedIntervals();
        var test = {
          "caseJSON" : {"interval":{"start_month":12,"start_year":2014,"end_month":12,"end_year":2017}},
          "caseVAR" : blogspotter     
        }

        console.log (blogspotter)    /// returns a valid JSON
        console.log(test.caseJSON.interval.start_month)  /// returns 12
        console.log(test.caseVAR.interval.start_month)   //// throws an error - "TypeError: Cannot read property "start_month" from undefined.
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="stackerFlow()" value="stackerFlow"/>
</body>
</html>
```